# Extract nested list element where element names are similar

Tags: r, list

I have a nested liste, resulted from a function. Where the top element names are reapeated in the element names further down.

```
$`1`
$`1`$`1`
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0

$`1`$`2`
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

$`2`
$`2`$`1`
[1] 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0

$`2`$`2`
[1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Is there a way to use an apply function (or whatever) to extract those vectors where the element and subelement names match. E.g. $`1`$`1` and $`2`$`2`. I have a huge list (4000 elements with 4000 subelements) so efficiency is thus a must.

Alternatively - I have figured out a way out of this mess by using ´melt()´, but it's too consuming for the size of my set. But if anyone know how to replicate the effect - giving a dataframe with 3 columns one for elementname, one for subelement name and one for the vector - that will also work.

Regards and thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a way to get a list of the vectors you want:

```
lapply(names(dat), function(x) dat[[x]][[x]])
```

In a data frame:

```
do.call("rbind",
        lapply(names(dat),
               function(x) data.frame(element = x,
                                      subelement = x,
                                      values = dat[[x]][[x]])
        )
)
```

Comment: the first code gives a list with correct number of elements but they are all NULL, while the last one gave the message which I guess stems from the fact that they are of unequal length: Error in data.frame(element = x, subelement = x, values = results[[x]][[x]]) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0.

Comment: The error with the second command is due to `NULL` values, but not due to unequal lengths.

Comment: @EndreGrünerOfstad  What is the output of `dat[['1']][['1']]`?

Comment: But I dont have any null values :P Or, when the list was it was without specific names so that they element and subelement names are just 1,2,3...I don't know if that matters. Here is the output: NULL :P

Comment: Don the names of the sublists and the vectors always match? Is the relationship 1:1?

Comment: it seems like the lists are not given any names, while the sublists do:   > names(results[[1]])  
[1] "1" "2" "3"  
> names(results[1])  
NULL  
> names(results)  
NULL    They are 1:1

Comment: It worked when I for small subset manually named lists and sublists. Is there then a lapplyway to rename sublistnames?

Comment: This should work: `lapply(as.character(seq(length(dat))), function(x) dat[[x]][[x]])`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much for your time and effort! :) I would have given you more +1 if I could :D

Answer (score 2):

You can `unlist` them without recursion to remove the top level list structure, and then use regex-assisted subsetting on the names of this result.

```
l <- list(`1`=list(`1`=rpois(6,1),`2`=rep(0,6)),`2`=list(`1`=rep(0,6),`2`=rpois(6,1)))
l2 <- unlist(l,recursive=F)
l2[grepl("([0-9]+)[.]\\1",names(l2))]
$`1.1`
[1] 2 0 2 4 1 0

$`2.2`
[1] 0 0 0 2 1 0
```